# Prove that if $(A,<)$ is a well ordering, then $(A,<)\nless(A,<)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, order-theory

Prove that if $(A,<)$ is a well ordering, then $(A,<)\nless(A,<)$

I'm trying to teach myself set theory for a course I am taking and am struggling a bit here. I need to suppose for contradiction that there is an isomorphism $f ∶ (A, <) → (pred(b, A, <), <)$ for some $b \in A$. Let $a\in A$ be the least such that $f(a) ≠ a$ and derive a contradiction from here.

Also the notation in my book is a bit hard to read. When I search online for help I wonder if perhaps the text only appears to be writing $<$ when it means $\prec$?

Excuse my ignorance, but I should also just make sure that I am reading this notation correctly. $(A,<)$ simply means some $A$ that is well-ordered yes? If not please feel free to correct me.

As I understand, the starting point I'm provided with says that there exists a function such that for some well ordered set, the predecessors of $b$ in set $A$  also belongs to a well ordered set. From here I need to assume $a$ to be my least valued element of my well ordered set? Moving from this is the suggestion to find a contradiction in $f(a)\neq a$. Here the logic loses me completely. If someone could guide me through this problem I'd greatly appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: It seems that you want to show that $A$ is not isomorphic to an initial segment of itself.  Consider, for $ f:A\to pred (b)$, the least $x$  such that $f(x)\ne x.$

Comment: @user254665 I apologize as I'm horribly new to this and flounder quite easily. Do you mean to say that we are trying to show that $A$ cannot biject to $pred(b)$ because for whatever least valued element the set has, it will have nothing to biject to? And cannot then be isomorphic to this segment you've specified?

Comment: Yes .See BrianO's answer. Further , if g is an order-preserving bijection of A to A then g is the identity on A by the same method. And if A,B are well-orderings,just one of these holds :(1) A is isomorphic to B,or (2) A is isomorphic to an initial segment of B , or (3) B is isomorphic to an initial segment of A.

Comment: Unlike for example the rationals with the usual ordering $(\Bbb Q, <)$, which has many order-isomorphisms (self-similarities), a well ordering is *rigid*: it has no nontrivial order-isomorphisms.

Comment: @user254665 so I added your observation and this last bit to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If $f\colon (A, <) \to (A,<)$ is 1-1, then $a\le f(a)$ for all $a\in A$*. Otherwise, there is a least $a_0\in A$ such that $f(a_0) < a_0$. Let $b = f(a_0)$. We have $b<a_0$, so $f(b) < f(a_0) = b$. But $b \le f(b)$, because $a\le f(a)$ for every $a<a_0$. Contradiction.

In particular we can't have $image(f)\subseteq pred(b)$ for any $b\in A$, because $f(b)\in (A\setminus pred(b))$.

---

By the way, here's a different proof, not by contradiction: we show  $a\le f(a)$ by well-founded induction on $a$ along $<$. Suppose $a\in A$ and $(\forall x<a)\, x\le f(x)$. Then for all $x<a$, $x\le f(x) < f(a)$, so
$$
\sup_{x<a} x \le \sup_{x<a} f(x) \le f(a).\tag{*}
$$
There are two cases:

If $a$ has no immediate predecessor, then $a = \sup_{x<a} x $, so $a\le 
f(a)$ by (*).

Otherwise, $a = b^+$ for some $b\in A$. From $b<a$ we get $f(b) < f(a)$. By induction hypothesis, $b\le f(b)$; thus $a = b^+ \le f(b)^+ \le f(a)$.

---

A corollary of this result, as @user254665 points out in a comment:

> Well-orderings are *rigid* with respect to order:
>    a well-ordering has no nontrivial order isomorphisms.

Unlike for example the rationals with the usual ordering $(\Bbb Q, <)$, which has many self-similarities i.e. order automorphisms, a well-ordering has only the identity function as an order automorphism.

Comment: That is,if f is 1-to-1 and x<y implies f(x)<f(y).

Comment: @user254665 Yes yes I'm well aware of that, and I'm glad that you are too. I'm spelling things out for the OP, who is probably not well aware of it. Let's not compete about this. I agree it was redundant.

Comment: My comment about f being 1-to-1 was intended for the OP, in case (s)he wasn't clear about it.+1.